# Cannot get Google Maps JavaScript API to load within Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bootstrap-modal

I am having trouble getting my Google Maps API to load within a popup modal.

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2>Warehousing</h2>
                        <p class="item-intro text-muted"></p>
                        <div id="warehouse-map-canvas"></div>
                        <p class="item-description">Short description</p> <p class="item-description">Short description</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Project</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41, -87);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: center,
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('warehouse-map-canvas');
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center,
            map: map,
            title: 'Warehouse'
        });

        /*google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
           map.setCenter(center);

           This bit of code seems to do nothing for me.
        });*/
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

What happens is I click and bring up the pop up modal and the map div space is filled out with displaying the google maps elements such as zoom bar, street view icon, etc. The map area within is grey however.

You can scroll, zoom, and otherwise pan but it will have no effect on the map. The map marker does appear when it is in the top left corner of the screen but sits upon a grey sea.

**SOLUTION:**

Using this bootstrap modal js and css (https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) I was able to get the map to refresh with this:

```
$('#portfolioModal3').on('shown', function () {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41, -87));
});
```

after the google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the map is constructed, it mesure the parent's dimensions for filling correctly.

When you initialize the page, with `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` your modal is not created yet, so when you show it, the dimensions are wrong.

To avoid this, you have to initialize the map only when you want to show the modal :

```
$('#portfolioModal3').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    initialize();
});
```

Comment: Where would I put this? In the script at the top? I have tried this similar method before and could not get it to load.

Comment: Anywhere after loading jquery, google map & bootstrap script. Use $(function() { ... }); to be sure your script is loaded.

Comment: I have tried this under the modified line `//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` with the modal just loading the div with the grey background from CSS

Comment: Have you got any error in the console ? Can we see this page ?

Comment: Only error from console I get is that the $ is undefined for that line to add in. I'm currently using Brackets to see the layout of HTML and CSS.

Comment: $ is undefined ? You don't have jQuery ?

Comment: I posted a link of the problem I'm having, just go to the warehouse section.

Comment: jquery is not yet loaded ... use document.addEventListener('onload', function() { $(function() { ... })  })

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that you are using the co-ordinates 41.xxxx and -87.xxxx which is causing a SyntaxError. Otherwise the code runs fine once I load the Google Maps JavaScript API and replace the co-ordinates with 41.0, -87.0.

Comment: The "xxx" is for hiding the location. Of course it will work ... You didn't load the modal itself.

Comment: I am actually using the whole values as you mentioned instead of xxxx. The map works, just only when the modal window is resized